# Writing functions that pass named arguments in python

Tags: python

I'm writing an office utilities library and want to provide an option via a named argument in one of my functions. This function calls several minor functions, but I'm getting confused over how to write the named argument.

I'm passing in the named argument with its default in the function to be called (`extract(subject, dir, recent_file=False`); then, the value of `recent_file` is passed to another function `read_rcsd(subject, dir, recent_file)`. I believe that's how you're supposed to do it, though I've also seen people write in the second function `recent_file=recent_file`.

```py
import win32com.client
import pandas as pd
import zhou_utils.sql as sql
import zhou_utils.oa_vars as oa
import numpy as np
from datetime import datetime
import os
import glob


# Extract and Transform utilities
"""Extraction"""

# define extraction methods
def latest_file(path, ending):
    '''
    Sample usage:

    def create_xwalk_df():
    xwalk_path = project_path + r'\Crosswalk'
    xwalk = latest_file(xwalk_path, "*CB Crosswalk*.*")
    return pd.read_excel(xwalk, nrows=609)  # NOTE: use rows up to grey rows

    :param path: string in form of '\Dir'
    :param ending: string in form of '*Target Keywords*.xlsx'
    :return: the latest file directory
    '''
    all_files = glob.glob(path + "\\" + ending)
    return max(all_files, key=os.path.getctime)


def read_rcsd(subject, dir, recent_file):
    """
    Use Pandas' read_csv to read in a particular subject with in-house datasets. Hardcoded header and footer lengths.
    Directory is a paramter to change path to either current downloads or test downloads.

    :param subject: string | <Science>
    :param dir: string | file directory in the R drive
    :return: DataFrame | downloaded dataframe of the RCSD subject
    """
    ATS_header = [2,3,4]
    ATS_footer = 19

    if recent_file==False:
        path = dir + '\\' + subject + '.csv'
    else:
        path = latest_file(dir, f"{subject}*.csv")  # if latest file is selected, filename must be formatted to begin
        # with the subject and be saved as .csv
        # TEST
        print(path)

    return pd.read_csv(path,
                       header=ATS_header,
                       skipfooter=ATS_footer,
                       engine='python', # use python as engine because it supports skipfooter
                       dtype=str, # read in all values as string. note that NaNs will still come in as a float
                       keep_default_na=False, # only interpret '' as an NaN value [float], this prevents reading in a legitimate name such as Na as literally not a number
                       na_values='') # see Pandas doc: "If keep_default_na is False, and na_values are specified, only the NaN values specified na_values are used for parsing."

def clean_csv(df):
    '''
    Create single index columns.

    :param df: dataframe to clean
    :return: cleaned dataframe
    '''
    # clean multi index headers
    def clean_columns(df):
        new_cols = []

        for col in df.columns:
            # create a list that looks like [one word, (first word, second word), one word, ...]
            if 'Unnamed' in col[0]:
                if 'Unnamed' in col[1]:
                    col = (col[2])
                else:
                    col = (col[1],col[2])
            new_cols.append(col)

        # join the list so that the columns look like [one word, first word second word, one word...]
        df.columns = [' '.join(x) if type(x) is tuple else x for x in new_cols]
    clean_columns(df)
    # drop the first row because it's blank
    # df = df[1:]
    return df

def extract(subject, dir, recent_file=False):
    '''
    Returns a cleaned exam download using previously defined functions.

    :param subject: exam subject | <'Science'>
    :param dir: directory | <R://Test Paths>
    :return: cleaned exam download
    '''
    return clean_csv(read_rcsd(subject, dir, recent_file))  #TODO: check if needs recent_file=recent_file

# TEST
ScienceDF = extract("Science", r'\Downloads\RCSD', recent_file=True)
```

Comment: one is a positional argument, one is a keyword argument. And both can work.

Comment: Ya the reason you'd see recent_file=recent_file is because, presumably, if they're calling the outer function, they don't need to interact with the inner function. Including recent_file=recent_file is for the people reading your source code, not the users, and as such, explicit is better than implicit.